# VAR Model: Non-stationarity of variables

Tags: econometrics, stationarity, vector-autoregression, macroeconomics

I am currently working on an empirical analysis in R. To give you some background information: I want to estimate a VAR-model to subsequently develop IRFs from it (using cholesky decomposition). My model has five variables: an industry production index, a consumer price index, an effective exchange rate index, 10-year government yields and the monetary policy rate. The data are available on a monthly basis. Except for the last two variables , I logarithmized all variables and calculated the yearly changes (not monthly changes). The real problem is that the variables are still all non-stationary. With the monetary policy rate and the government yield (which, as I said, I haven't changed), I don't think that's so bad, but with the other three variables I'm not sure that non-stationarity will cause problems.

Does anyone here know if this could cause problems for further analysis?

Thank you very much in advance and have a great weekend!

[image]

Comment: If nonstationarity is present, it will cause problems. If it is mild, the problems will be mild. If it is pronounced, problems can get worse. Why do you believe the variables are nonstationary? What kind of nonstationarity do you suspect? Could you perhaps supply graphs of transformed variables that you would like to use in the model? Another thing: taking yearly differences of monthly data will result in overlapping observations. As a result, I would expect the effective sample size to drop considerably and the effective standard errors to explode.

Comment: @RichardHardy: I have added graphs above. I did an ADF for each of the variables which states unit roots for each variable . I have to say that I also divide the period into two samples to compare them later (Sample 1: 1999 till 2008 [118 observations], Sample 2: 2011-2019 [108 observations]). But that doesn't change the results of the ADF. I use yearly differences because it's often used to calculate the inflation rate. So I did the same with the production index and the exchange rate index.